# How to bind an array of objects in a tabular format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, functional-programming

I am trying to solve this question, maybe it's the wording of the question that's complicated for me. But the task is basically to count the instances of all the strings in an array of objects.

I have tried some functional utility methods like filter and reduce but just couldn't get it right.

```
    let users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Babloo",
    
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Raam",
    
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Shyam",
    
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Balraam",
    
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Sunder",
    
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Balraam",
    
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Mahesh",
    
  }
]
// Bind this Array in a tabular format.
```

I expect output to be

```
Name | Repeat Count

Balram | 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find number a duplicates and it's name in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674092/find-number-a-duplicates-and-its-name-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Consider using a `Map` and `Array#filter`.

You can also create a `table` using the result.

```js
const table = document.querySelector("#table");

const 
  users=[{id:1,name:"Babloo"},{id:2,name:"Raam"},{id:3,name:"Shyam"},{id:4,name:"Balraam"},{id:5,name:"Sunder"},{id:6,name:"Balraam"},{id:7,name:"Mahesh"}],

  res = Array.from(users.reduce((m, { name }) => (m.set(name, (m.get(name) || 0) + 1), m), new Map()));
  
res.forEach(([name, count]) => {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  const tdName = document.createElement("td");
  const tdCount = document.createElement("td");

  tdName.innerText = name;
  tdCount.innerText = count;

  tr.appendChild(tdName);
  tr.appendChild(tdCount);

  table.appendChild(tr);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

```css
#table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
</table>
```

Comment: can you explain to me , what is going on in the reduce function?

Comment: @siddhant `reduce` callback will run for every item in the array and inside it we are incrementing the count of `name`. I've updated my answer, creating a `table` with the data. You can read more about `reduce` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and `Map` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#reduce` to group by `name`. Then use `Object.entries` combined with `Array#map` like this.

```js
let users = [{id:1,name:"Babloo",},{id:2,name:"Raam",},{id:3,name:"Shyam",},{id:4,name:"Balraam",},{id:5,name:"Sunder",},{id:6,name:"Balraam",},{id:7,name:"Mahesh",}];

const groupingData = users.reduce((acc, {name}) => 
                    (acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + 1, acc), {});
const result = Object.entries(groupingData).map(([key, value]) => 
                    ({name: key, Repeat_Count: value}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: yes, it did. But what about the part where we have to present in a tabular format? is it some form of a technical term?

Comment: It depends on your language you are using. From your normalized data, you can iterate as you wish. @siddhant